# Cerrar sesión de Firebase después de un período de tiempo

Tags: firebase, flutter

Hola tengo un loging con firebase, deseo que después de un tiempo de inactividad se cierre la sesión no encuentro documentación sobre esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar este plugin https://pub.dev/packages/local_session_timeout

En el cual puedes configurar un tiempo de inactividad, para 2 casos:

```
final sessionConfig = SessionConfig(
    invalidateSessionForAppLostFocus: const Duration(seconds: 15),
    invalidateSessionForUserInactivity: const Duration(seconds: 30));
```

`invalidateSessionForAppLostFocus` : Cuando estás inactivo y has salido del app.
`invalidateSessionForUserInactivity` : Cuando estás inactivo pero aún dentro del app

Con estos métodos puedes escuchar esos eventos:

```dart
sessionConfig.stream.listen((SessionTimeoutState timeoutEvent) {
    if (timeout == SessionTimeoutState.userInactivityTimeout) {
        // handle user  inactive timeout
        // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/auth");
    } else if (imeout == SessionTimeoutState.appFocusTimeout) {
        // handle user  app lost focus timeout
        // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/auth");
    }
});
```

Solo te quedaría llamar al método logout de Firebase :

```dart
 FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
```

Comment: Gracias amigo siempre apoyando al caído, ya lo reviso